# Compiler warning using if statements in C

Tags: c, warnings

I am trying to compare the user input to a string, and every time I compile, it gives me this warning:

> warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 2)

This warning occurs in every single "if" statement. I don't know if it will affect the actual result but I really want to know how to get rid of it.  Here's the offending code:

```
void AddBorder(unsigned char R[WIDTH][HEIGHT], unsigned char G[WIDTH][HEIGHT], unsigned char B[WIDTH][HEIGHT],
                  char color[SLEN], int border_width)
{
  int x,y,a=0,b=0,c=0;
  printf("Enter border width:");
  scanf("%d", &border_width);
  printf("Availble border colors: black, white, red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, pink, orange.\n");
  printf("Select border color from the options:");
  scanf("%s", color);

  if (strcmp(color, "black" == 0))
  {
    a=0;
    b=0;
    c=0;
  }

  if (strcmp(color, "pink" == 0))
  {
    a=255;
    b=192;
    c=203;
  }
  if (strcmp(color, "white" == 0))
  {
    a=255;
    b=255;
    c=255;
  }

  for (y=0; y<HEIGHT; y++)
  {
    for (x=0; x<WIDTH; x++)
    {
      R[x][y]=0;
      G[x][y]=0;
      B[x][y]=0;
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (strcmp(color, "black" == 0))
                              ^ wrong placement of )
```

Your placement of `)` in this is above statement is wrong-

```
if (strcmp(color, "black") == 0)         //correct statement
```

And similar for all `if` conditions

Answer (score 1):

You have several instances where your parentheses are in the wrong place, e.g.

```
if (strcmp(color, "black" == 0))
```

should be:

```
if (strcmp(color, "black") == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've put the `== 0` inside the parentheses. Try this instead:

```
if (strcmp(color, "black") == 0)
{
    a=0;
    b=0;
    c=0;
}

if (strcmp(color, "pink") == 0)
{
    a=255;
    b=192;
    c=203;
}

if (strcmp(color, "white") == 0)
{
    a=255;
    b=255;
    c=255;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `if` statements to

```
if (strcmp(color, "black") == 0)
```

Because, I believe what you want is to compare the two strings, and check the return value of `strcmp()` with `0`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in all the strcmp(color, "block" == 0) in if. Instead of this you have to use strcmp(color, "black") == 0. So modify you code like below.
It will not give the warnings now.

```
void AddBorder(unsigned char R[WIDTH][HEIGHT], unsigned char G[WIDTH][HEIGHT], unsigned char B[WIDTH][HEIGHT],
                  char color[SLEN], int border_width)
{
  int x,y,a=0,b=0,c=0;
  printf("Enter border width:");
  scanf("%d", &border_width);
  printf("Availble border colors: black, white, red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, pink, orange.\n");
  printf("Select border color from the options:");
  scanf("%s", color);

  if (strcmp(color, "black") == 0)
  {
    a=0;
    b=0;
    c=0;
  }

  if (strcmp(color, "pink") == 0)
  {
    a=255;
    b=192;
    c=203;
  }
  if (strcmp(color, "white") == 0)
  {
    a=255;
    b=255;
    c=255;
  }

  for (y=0; y<HEIGHT; y++)
  {
    for (x=0; x<WIDTH; x++)
    {
      R[x][y]=0;
      G[x][y]=0;
      B[x][y]=0;
    }
  } 
}
```